# Eager Loading to resolve n+1 queries Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a

```
User 
has_many :friends, through: :friendships
has_many :blocked_friends, through: blocked_users
```

And with The network method I am trying to get current users friends in 2 levels. 
The problem is that Running this method for the first time gives me individual queries for each 1st level friend friends lookup. After I run it the second time it acts like it is supposed to (giving me constant amount of 6 queries). What is the problem here?

```
def network
    User.includes(friends: [:friends]).find(self.id)        
    all_friends = []
    all_friends << self # add current user
    all_friends += self.friends # add user's friends
    self.friends.each {|i| all_friends += i.friends} # add user's friend friends
    all_friends.uniq - self.blocked_friends # take away blocked friends
end
```

Comment: what if you do `all_friends += self.friends.includes(:friend)`

Comment: Doesn't work. It does not find and add the second layer of friends (because as far as I understand, `includes` does not return the friends, just loads them in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you do cache over your database, not over your Rails application.

Let's get a look about your `network` method :

```
def network
    User.includes(friends: [:friends]).find(self.id)
    # Will do some queries like your User selection,
    # its friend selection, and sub-friends selection.
    # SQL queries are done, but the result is sent to nowhere.

    all_friends = []
    all_friends << self # add current user
    all_friends += self.friends # add user's friends
    # Now, you request AGAIN the friends of the user, but the
    # variable is not the same ! self is not equal to
    # User.find(self.id). It represents the same object, but
    # not exactly the same object_id in your Rails application.
    # In other words,
    # self == User.find(self.id) => true
    # self === User.find(self.id) => false !

    # [ ... ]
end
```

To be more efficient, you should do this :

```
def network
  self_with_eager_loading = User.includes(:friends => :friends).find(self.id)
  all_friends = []
  all_friends << self_with_eager_loading
  all_friends += self_with_eager_loading.friends
  self_with_eager_loading.friends.each {|i| all_friends += i.friends}
  [ ... ]
end
```

In this example, the variable `self` (containing no eager loading) is not used. Only `self_with_eager_loading` is used.

**Just a little note**: You should not do that. Use `User.find(self).id` is crappy in an instance class method. To be beautiful, your code should looks like this :

```
def network
  all_friends = []
  all_friends << self
  all_friends += self.friends.includes(:friends)
  self.friends.each {|i| all_friends += i.friends}
  [ ... ]
end
```

When you execute this and you go out of this method, your variable `self` always contains `friends` and sub-`friends`, you can use it everywhere.

Comment: After doing all the queries that I expect, It still does queries that take each of my friends ids and looks in the friendship table for their friends (separately). After I run it again it only does the expected queries. I presume that is the database cache working, but this still did not resolve the problem.